# Need help in many to many query in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlite

i have two tables `Coupon` and `Tags` they have many to many relation now i want to create some sql view satisfy following situation

1- Need count with tag that how many coupons are there in every tag ( Done )

2- Need to get a list of tags sort by popular tags ( popular tags is the tag which have most coupons )

3- Need count of all coupon created in last 7 days on every tag

the sql view which i have written for first condition is following

**SQLVIEW**

```
Create VIEW [dbo].[TagsWithCount] AS

  SELECT Tag.Id as Id , Tag.Name as TagName ,Tag.description as Description,
   COUNT(*) AS CouponCount
   FROM Tags AS Tag
   inner JOIN couponsTotags c ON c.Tagid = Tag.id  
    GROUP BY Tag.Name , Tag.Id ,Tag.description
    GO
```

and it gives me the following results

[image]

how can i get , rest of things can anyone help me , Tell me if you need any other detail

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ORDER BY CouponCount DESC` for (2)

Comment: For the second one you can just Order by your view by CouponCount Desc but for the third one what is the format of your datetime field , is it in Coupon's table?

Comment: @Smartboy are all situation should fit in one query?

Comment: CreateDate is a field in Tags table format : datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Create VIEW [dbo].[TagsWithCount] AS

    select * from  (SELECT Tag.Id as Id , Tag.Name as TagName ,Tag.description as Description,
       case when DATEDIFF(day, CreateDate, systemdate)<=7 then 'Its sevendays old'
else 'its more than 7 days old' end as SevendaysOldStatus,COUNT(*) AS CouponCount    
       FROM Tags AS Tag
       inner JOIN couponsTotags c ON c.Tagid = Tag.id  
        GROUP BY Tag.Name , Tag.Id ,Tag.description,CreateDate) temp
    order by CouponCount desc
        GO
```

Verify for sytem date not tried in any editor but hope will work for your requirement

Comment: all good but instead of `order by CouponCount desc` we should use    `ORDER BY CouponCount DESC` as @Ash said , Thanks to all

Comment: sorry @Rahul , its giving wrong count in `SevendaysOld` . I mean if a tag have 3 coupons it will show 3 its `SevendaysOld` should be a bit field to show weather this tag is 7 days old or not , Hope you get my point